# How to accept a code block on a method C#

Tags: c#, methods, extending

I'm writing an extensions library for C#, and I'm wondering if it's possible to accept code blocks on a method call. Something like below:

```
foo()
{
  var bar = 0;
};
```

Or something like this would also do:

```
foo(
{
var bar = 0; //As an argument to the method 
});
```

Comment: Ya. You can use delegates. See this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866347/lambda-anonymous-function-as-a-parameter

Comment: Thanks @GiladGreen, that's extremely helpful! Either mark this question as duplicate or add your comment as an answer.

Comment: For some reason it won't let me add it as an answer but just puts it as a comment.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in a delegate/lambda to accomplish this.

```
public void foo(Action del)
{
    var local = del;
    if (local != null)
    {
        local();
    }
}

foo(() => 
{
var bar = 0;
});
```

You can read more [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2012/03/02/c-delegates-actions-funcs-lambdaskeeping-it-super-simple/)