# Xamarin.Forms - How do I make a custom view with a clickable image?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, view, xamarin.forms

I am making an app that has a grid of many images that need to handle click events. I am able to make a single image clickable with this,

```
        Image clickableImage = new Image();
        clickableImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("image.png");

        imageTap.Tapped += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Image clicked!");
        };

        clickableImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(imageTap);
```

but I need to have >20 clickable images. Is there a way to create something like an Angular2 template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Custom Control in your shared project itself which inherits from image and supports click and use it through out your application.

```
ClickableImage : Image 
{
      public ClickableImage()
      {
           Tapped += (sender, e) => 
           {
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Image clicked!");
           };
      }
}
```

Comment: Using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866347/lambda-anonymous-function-as-a-parameter, I was able to pass functions as parameters to the Tapped method.

Comment: If you have improvements, post your own answer which can prove helpful for others too.

Comment: There, added my updated code as an answer. Sorry it took so long

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Rohit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38716551/1155650), I was able to create a custom control that I modified to take an anonymous function as a parameter. Here is the code:

```
class ClickableImage : Image
{
    private TapGestureRecognizer tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();

    public ClickableImage(Action action)
    {
        tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => 
        {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Image Clicked w/ Lambda");
           action();
        };

        GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
    }
}
```